# Threading.Timer Doesn't Run For A Second Time

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to implement a timer structure which runs a function periodically. To do that, I used threading.Timer object like below:

```
class AClass:

    def function(self):
        print('Begins ...')
        # some operations here ...
        print('Ends!')

    def trigger(self):
        self.market_listener_thread = threading.Timer(DATA_COLLECTOR_FREQUENCY, self.listen, [], {}).start()

class MainClass:
    def anotherFunction:
        aClass = AClass()
        aClass.trigger()
```

Here my function runs once and prints `Begins ...` and `Ends!`. But it does not run for a second time and also does not produce an error, warning anything. What is wrong here?

Comment: How do you call `MainClass.anotherFunction`? A `threading.Timer` object will only run once, when started.

Comment: @jofrev Yes, I didn't know that it calls once, I thought it is similar to the Timer in java. Thanks.